# Splunk: Apache Access & Apache Errors in One Project

Tags: logging, syslog, splunk, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I want to use rsyslog to send to Splunkstorm. I want to send Apache Access & Apache Errors to the same project. According to [this answer](http://answers.splunk.com/answers/72489/multiple-inputs-for-api-in-one-storm-project), I can either create two separate projects (which to me seems like a waste of the maximum 3 allowed) OR I can add a marker to my event. Therefore

1. Can the marker be any value/pair,    such as `tag=\"access\"` and     `tag=\"error\"` (I'm using rsyslog    $template line syntax )?
2. Which sourcetype do I use? *syslog*    or *generic single line data*
3. Do these two rsyslog configs look acceptable? access_log is *ncsa
   combined* & the error_log is Apache 2.2 standard.

$template access,"<%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %msgid% tag=\"access\"] %msg%"

$template  error,"<%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %msgid% tag=\"error\"] %msg%"

Comment: The folks at Splunk Answers want to convince me to use the Universal Forwarder. They cannot or don't want to answer these questions.